# String '10/8/2020' was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

```cs
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("10/8/2020","dd/MM/yyyy", null));
    }
}
```

Returns the error

```
Run-time exception (line 7): String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Stack Trace:

[System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.]
   at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
   at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider)
   at Program.Main() :line 7
```

Not sure why this problem occurs. Can someone please shed some light?

Comment: You are expecting two digits for the month, but your string only has one. A valid date would be `"10/08/2020"`

Comment: It must be 08 to match MM. Use M (just 1) instead to match 8 — refer to M and MM in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: Your parse exact method expects dd/MM/yyyy but gets dd/M/yyyy instead

Comment: seems it's better to use "d/M/yyyy" in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you use `dd/M/yyyy` format while parsing or add 0 in front of month, make it two digits

`Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("10/08/2020","dd/MM/yyyy", null));`

Or

`Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("10/8/2020","dd/M/yyyy", null));`